# Sublime Text Plugin Modification

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

So I found this plugin: https://gist.github.com/KatsuomiK/3542836

And it is very close to what I'm looking for. I am trying to use sublime text 3 for note taking, and need some way to store images in my notes. Since sublime is a text editor, I do not hope to have actual inline images. Instead, what makes the most sense to me is to have local file links which I can click to open up an image. This plugin has the same click link feature, but it opens web links in a browser rather than local files. I'm actually not sure on what the most user friendly option would be, but here is one idea.

Hover mouse over local link (e.g. /Users/gus/image.jpg)
Press some hotkey
Image opens up either in preview or the quick look feature in OSX (would be nice since you could close with a simple spacebar)

If necessary there could be some kind of tag for a local link.

I am not experienced with making sublime plugins, but something tells me this could be a quite simple endeavor for a skilled coder. If you can help me out I would greatly appreciate it (and so would anyone trying to use sublime for note taking and even coding at times)

Comment: I don't have the time to help you with the detail right now, but to open a file from python (when the plugin print "not url" for now I'ld say), you can run the following command: os.system("open "+url). You need to import os at the top of your python file. This should open the file with the default application (for a picture, preview). You can also force the application you want to open the file with, but I'm not sure it's a good idea.

Comment: I made the change, but I do not know how to make it work as a plugin. How can I make it so that I press a key combo and the code is ran for the text below my cursor?